# Compiling Dwm to Arch Linux. Xft.h missing?

Tags: arch-linux, compiling, c, dwm, xft

Trying to compile the Dwm Tile Manager (that uses Xorg ) on Arch Linux currently produces the following error ([original attached file](http://ix.io/2ztt)):

```
dwm build options:
CFLAGS   = -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Os -I/usr/include/X11 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -DVERSION="6.2" -DXINERAMA
LDFLAGS  = -L/usr/lib -lX11 -lXinerama -lfontconfig -lXft
CC       = cc
cc -c -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Os -I/usr/include/X11 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -DVERSION=\"6.2\" -DXINERAMA drw.c
drw.c:6:10: fatal error: X11/Xft/Xft.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <X11/Xft/Xft.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:18: drw.o] Error 1
```

Does this indicate that the `Xft.h` library is required to compile Dwm?

The Arch Linux package manager fails to install Xorg-server (which contains `Xft.h`) leaving this keyring error ([original attached file](http://ix.io/2zu0)):

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
warning: dependency cycle detected:
warning: harfbuzz will be installed before its freetype2 dependency

Packages (21) freetype2-2.10.2-1  graphite-1:1.3.14-1  harfbuzz-2.7.2-1  libepoxy-1.5.4-2  libevdev-1.9.1-1  libfontenc-1.1.4-3  libgudev-234-1  libinput-1.16.1-1  libpng-1.6.37-3  libwacom-1.5-1  libxfont2-2.0.4-3  libxkbfile-1.1.0-2  mtdev-1.1.6-1  pixman-0.40.0-1  xf86-input-libinput-0.30.0-1  xkeyboard-config-2.30-2  xorg-fonts-encodings-1.0.5-2  xorg-server-common-1.20.9-2  xorg-setxkbmap-1.3.2-2  xorg-xkbcomp-1.4.3-1  xorg-server-1.20.9-2

Total Installed Size:  23.80 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] checking keyring...
downloading required keys...
:: Import PGP key 3B94A80E50A477C7, "Jan Alexander Steffens (heftig) <heftig@archlinux.org>"? [Y/n] error: key "3B94A80E50A477C7" could not be looked up remotely
error: required key missing from keyring
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

Is there an alternative way I can obtain `Xft.h`?

Comment: when's the last time you've run `pacman -Syu`? in my experience keyring errors are just from not having updated the arch linux keyring package in too long

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. pacman -Syu hasn't changed the behaviour in this case.

Comment: 1) Are you saying that `pacman -Syu` succeeds, and your system is up to date, but you are still getting the error related to the missing key? Or that `pacman -Syu` fails somehow? 2) Doesn't `gpg --list-key --homedir /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/ 3B94A80E50A477C7` list any key? If so, you may be able to import the missing key with: `sudo gpg --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --homedir /etc/pacman.d/gnupg 19802F8B0D70FC30` (`3B94A80E50A477C7` is apparently a subkey of this one).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the compiler complains about not being able to find `X11/Xft/Xft.h` in the include directories on your system.

You can query pacman's file database to know which packages, including non-installed ones, provide a file:

```bsh
sudo pacman -Fy    # the database likely needs to be refreshed
pacman -F Xft.h
```

Or, if you have the more feature-rich `pkgfile` installed (which maintains its own file database):

```bsh
pkgfile Xft.h
```

Both will tell you that `usr/include/X11/Xft/Xft.h` is provided by `libxft`.

Note that you may also take advantage of existing packages: `dwm` [exists in the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dwm/) and, even if you need to compile your own version, you may still look at the dependencies ("depends", "makedepends") declared in the `PKGBUILD` file provided there.

Reports about issues with heftig@archlinux.org's gpg key have come up more than once on the Arch Linux forums in the past few months [[1]](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=255968) [[2]](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=256664). If your `archlinux-keyring` package is up to date and you still see errors related to the missing key you can try importing the key `3B94A80E50A477C7` happens to be a sub-key of:

```
sudo gpg --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net \
  --homedir /etc/pacman.d/gnupg 19802F8B0D70FC30
```